# Access Docker Container Webserver

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-container

Short notation of my network setup

**A** - Fedora23  [ ip 192.168.1.11 ]

**B** - Ubuntu Docker Container which runs in **A** [ ip 172.17.0.2 ]

**C** - Fedora23 (one more system in my network)  [ ip 192.168.1.10 ]

firewall is disabled in both **A** and **C**.

---

I have created container using below command

```
docker run --name development-phase -d -p 5000:80 -v /var/www/public development
```

**note:** **ubuntu:latest** is the parent of development image

I can able to access the container webserver from **A**

`http://192.168.1.11:5000`

but I can't able to access from **C**.

`http://192.168.1.11:5000` it is getting redirect to `http://172.17.0.2/?SID=iaumi0rm68nlp1qnb5l0rnfdo5` it throws ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

but I can able to access the webserver of A `http:/192.168.1.11`

in running container I can't able to check firewall status, ufw and iptables bash command not found. I think firewall is not a problem otherwise I can't get success in **A**.

I am new to docker as well as networking area so if you need any additional info please mention in comment.

Comment: So you're able to connect with localhost but not with the remote name /remote IP?

Comment: yes correct. I am working with ssh command. as per telnet result localhost worked. upto now I can't get visual confirmation. @zhqiat

Comment: Really Stupid question. Is your web server currently running inside the docker?

Comment: yes apache running inside docker container

Answer (score 1):

Good News: Looks like your docker is fine.
Bad News: Sounds like a firewall issue. I'd disable UFW (if enabled) and check iptables.

There is some help items on the [UBuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593027&page=2&s=9402fd21a9f80c15c429404fd932e1c9) which have your exact symptoms.

> I'm trying to set up a small Intranet system to run OpenERP or similar using browser-based clients. I have an Ubuntu machine running 10.04 desktop edition to act as a temporary/testing server until we set up a proper, dedicated machine with 10.04 server edition.
>
> I have installed Apache2 from the repos and it is up and running fine - locally. That is the problem, I can't access the server from other machines on the LAN. Ping works, btw.
>
> So I've been reading tutorials and howtos for the past week, but for the life of me, I can't find what I'm doing wrong. The standard Apache setup seems to be made to "just work", so although I've looked at the various configuration files mentioned in the tutorials, I haven't actually changed anything.

Comment: both ufw and iptables command not found in container. 'bash: iptables: command not found'. except container all system firewalls are disabled.

Comment: Is that even possible? IPtables is built into the os. try `sudo iptables -L` and post the output?

Comment: no luck. I think docker image is skeleton of ubuntu OS nothing to install build in just very basics things only installed build in that is why it is so light weight. me only install what are the things needed.

Comment: Did you check the fw of the computer that the container is running on ?

Comment: docker ps list my container (running). if fw mean firewall, except container all the system firewall stop (ubuntu docker container running on fedora 23 os). fedora 23 fw also stop